# Moving system partition for EC2 Instance to new volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What is the best way to move a system partition, ie. /var, /opt to a larger volume that is attached during the EC2 instance creation? For example, I want to create a generic AMI but if I use this AMI for MySQL server then I need to attach a larger volume for /var. Is there a way during the creation process to tell it to provision the instance with /var on the additional volume?

Answer (score -1):

The concern you mentioned doesn't actually exist in real life. You don't need to specify the volume or size of `/var` or `/opt` directories. Linux directory structure is mounted to the root storage device. Any sub-directories(e.g. `/var`, `/etc`) can expand unless there is available free space in root storage. You don't need extra parrtition for that.

In your case the solution is: while launching new instance from your generic AMI in `Step 4: Add Storage` choose your desired storage size!